# Which of the 'Variable Length Subnet Masking technique' is correct and most useful for most users?

Tags: networking

Method 1:

- Major Network: 192.168.1.0/24
- Available IP addresses in major
- network: 254
- Number of IP addresses needed: 27
- Available IP addresses in allocated subnets: 229
- About 10.55% of available major network address space is used
- About 10.63% of subnetted network address space is used

| Subnet Name | Needed Size | Allocated Size | Address | Mask | Dec Mask | Assignable Range | Broadcast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6 | 8 | 192.168.1.0 | /29 | 255.255.255.248 | 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.6 | 192.168.1.7 |
| B | 5 | 8 | 192.168.1.8 | /29 | 255.255.255.248 | 192.168.1.9 - 192.168.1.14 | 192.168.1.15 |
| C | 4 | 4 | 192.168.1.16 | /30 | 255.255.255.252 | 192.168.1.17 - 192.168.1.18 | 192.168.1.19 |
| D | 3 | 4 | 192.168.1.20 | /30 | 255.255.255.252 | 192.168.1.21 - 192.168.1.22 | 192.168.1.23 |
| E | 2 | 2 | 192.168.1.24 | /31 | 255.255.255.254 | 192.168.1.25 - 192.168.1.24 | 192.168.1.25 |
| F | 1 | 1 | 192.168.1.26 | /32 | 255.255.255.255 | 192.168.1.27 - 192.168.1.25 | 192.168.1.26 |

Method 2:

- Major Network: 192.168.1.0/24
- Available IP addresses in major network: 254
- Number of IP addresses needed: 21
- Available IP addresses in allocated subnets: 28
- About 16% of available major network address space is used
- About 75% of subnetted network address space is used

| Subnet Name | Needed Size | Allocated Size | Address | Mask | Dec Mask | Assignable Range | Broadcast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6 | 6 | 192.168.1.0 | /29 | 255.255.255.248 | 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.6 | 192.168.1.7 |
| B | 5 | 6 | 192.168.1.8 | /29 | 255.255.255.248 | 192.168.1.9 - 192.168.1.14 | 192.168.1.15 |
| C | 4 | 6 | 192.168.1.16 | /29 | 255.255.255.248 | 192.168.1.17 - 192.168.1.22 | 192.168.1.23 |
| D | 3 | 6 | 192.168.1.24 | /29 | 255.255.255.248 | 192.168.1.25 - 192.168.1.30 | 192.168.1.31 |
| E | 2 | 2 | 192.168.1.32 | /30 | 255.255.255.252 | 192.168.1.33 - 192.168.1.34 | 192.168.1.35 |
| F | 1 | 2 | 192.168.1.36 | /30 | 255.255.255.252 | 192.168.1.37 - 192.168.1.38 | 192.168.1.39 |

Comment: VLSM is dead. It died along with classful networking in 1993, 30 years ago. Please leave it dead and buried. Today we use CIDR.

Comment: Which of the VLSM (CIDR) Subnet calculation is correct?

Comment: If you don't do your homework yourself you learn nothing.

Comment: Can you please tell me which one is correct? "your homework yourself you learn nothing" - I've been working on this for the last 48 hours. And its almost 12:30 AM here..